List all associations of a model
I'm looking for a way to list all associations of a model. This is to run some consistency background validation of the big and old database. Too many models to manually discover them and error prone.
I know about Model.new.attributes method. But I don't see which attribute is an association, which model it is, whether it is polymorphic.
Maybe I can assume that something_id is an association and look for something_type attribute to know whether it is polymorphic. But then I can't catch one-to-many and even harder for many-to-many associations.
Is there a more reliable way to do so?

Use reflect_on_all_associations on the class. This will return an Array of subclasses of ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection (unfortunately undocumented) for each association. For example, a belongs_to association will return a ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection.
#klass will return the associated class, #name will return the association name, and from #association_class you can figure out the type of association.
For example.
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end

# Parent
p Child.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:klass)


There is a tiny smidgin of documentation in the parent class ActiveRecord::Reflection::MacroReflection.

Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Although dealing with all types is not so easy. For example #klass is raising on polymorphic associations and joins can't be done on proc associations that take current object as a parameter. But anyway, these are very different problems.
